# Play sound ONLY ONCE

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a small asteroid avoiding game and when my lives are over I'm executing the following code:

```
gameover.play();
```

while gameover is defined like so:

```
var gameover = new Audio('gameover.wav');
```

When I execute the code, it loops the sound and I want to play it just once, how would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Please show exactly how gameover is defined. "defined as gameover.wav" doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: @aldel Just edited it.

Comment: By default audio does not loop. The most likely explanation is that you're calling the play method multiple times, but it's impossible to say for sure without seeing a complete example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe setting the [`loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loop) property to `false` will accomplish your goal.

```
var birdSound = new Audio('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4929.mp3');
birdSound.loop = false;
birdSound.play();
```

```js
var birdSound = new Audio('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4929.mp3');
birdSound.loop = false;
birdSound.play();

var statusElem = document.getElementById('status');
var startTime = Date.now();
updateStatus();

function updateStatus(){
  if (birdSound.ended){
    statusElem.innerText = 'Stopped';
  } else {
    statusElem.innerText = 'Playing (' + ( ( Date.now() - startTime ) / 1000 )  + ')';
    window.setTimeout(updateStatus, 50);
  }
}
```

```html
Audio Status: <span id="status">Playing</span>
```

Tested in:

- Chrome 44.0.2403.155 (64-bit)
- Firefox 40.0.2
- Safari 8.0.6
- Vivaldi 1.0.94.2 <sub>(for giggles)</sub>

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it still loops the sound.

Comment: @JasonSmith - Sounds like you've got another issue going on in your code. Seems to work just fine in Chrome version 44.